# What implicitly occurs during numpy addition?

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy

What can occur when doing numpy array addition? I have made a CUDA application in C++ calculating squared distances, which I interface to Python using cdll. The Python wrapper looks like this:

```
def sqdist(X: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:

    # Organize input and output
    N, D = X.shape
    X = X.astype(np.float32)
    Y = np.zeros((N, N)).astype(np.float32)

    # Prepare memory pointers
    dataIn = X.ctypes.data_as(cdll.POINTER(cdll.c_float))
    dataOut = Y.ctypes.data_as(cdll.POINTER(cdll.c_float))

    # Call the sqdist dll
    cdll.load(_get_build_default())
    cdll.computeSquaredEuclideanDistances(dataIn, N, D, dataOut)
    cdll.unload()

    # Return as numpy array
    return Y
```

Note the conversion to float32 in order to use numpy ctypes `data_as` (CUDA uses 32-bit float). Now, comparing output of this method to the output of `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(a,a,metric='sqeuclidean')`, I find an odd behavior:

Assume I have some data `Xcl` (numpy array):

Input [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8EMZ.png):

```
a = Xcl
b = Xcl + np.zeros(Xcl.shape)
print(a.dtype, type(a), a.shape)
print(b.dtype, type(b), b.shape)
print(np.all(a == b))
```

Output [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8EMZ.png):

```
float32 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (582, 115)
float64 <class 'numpy.ndarray'> (582, 115)
True
```

Input [2]:

```
scipydist = scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(a, a, metric='sqeuclidean')
cudadist1 = cuda.sqdist(a)
cudadist2 = cuda.sqdist(b)

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 5))
plt.subplot(131)
plt.imshow(scipydist, vmax=3000)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title("scipydist")
plt.subplot(132)
plt.imshow(cudadist1, vmax=3000)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title("cudadist1")
plt.subplot(133)
plt.imshow(cudadist2, vmax=3000)
plt.colorbar()
plt.title("cudadist2")
plt.show()
```

Output[2]:

[image]

I.e. I get a different output of my CUDA algorithm depending on whether or not I add zeros to my input. **How (the hell) can that happen? What implicitly occurs during a numpy addition?** The same goes for multiplying with `np.ones`.

Comment: I suspect this is type promotion, your `np.zeros` array is likely defaulting to `np.float64`.

Comment: Yes, the np.zeros promote to float64. Please look at the answer I posted below. float64 must have a different underlying memory layout then?

Comment: No, a `np.float64` array can be any order, but newly created arrays *should* default to 'C' order, AFAIK, but I am looking for the relevant docs

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga is correct for the first example.  When you create a new ndarray in python, it defaults to double precision.
'
Try replacing your second line in the example the following: `b = Xcl + np.zeros_like(Xcl)`

Answer (score 0):

Alright. This appears to be due to some sort of memory layout. Using the `np.astype` in my wrapper, it defaults to `order='K'`:

> K means as close to the order the array elements appear in memory as possible

Whereas the CUDA application expects data to be layed out in order C. Updating the wrapper to the following fixed the issue:

```
X = X.astype(np.float32, order='C')
Y = np.zeros((N, N)).astype(np.float32, order='C')
```

Hence I guess the numpy addition implicitly reorders the underlying data to whatever suits it?.

Comment: What is the order of `Xcl`?

Comment: How do I check the order of a numpy array?

Comment: `X.flags`, `X.__array_interface__` and `X.strides` all give useful information, thought it isn't always easy to interpret.  Look at these before and after the `astype` to see what changes when you force an `C` order.